# how to add a lightbox to images in Ubercart cart?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

Can I apply "Custom formatters" presets to Ubercart cart ?

I need to customize the html code of the images in the cart.

I'm trying to do it with hook_form_alter but what I get is the output html and it is too late to modify it:

> [#value] = > < a
>   href="/website/node/87">< img 
>   src="http://localhost/website/path/to/picture
>   1.png" alt="" title=""  class="imagecache imagecache-cart"
>   width="100" height="221" />

I need to add "rel=lightbox" attribute to  and change href path.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to look at hook_uc_image_widget. I can't find the API documentation for it, but you can see an [example implementation](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/jqzoom/uc_jqzoom/uc_jqzoom.module?revision=1.1.2.2&view=markup&pathrev=DRUPAL-6--1) in the [jQZoom module](http://drupal.org/project/jqzoom).

Comment: are you sure this function is for the cart and not the catalog ? There is alredy lightbox2 trigger (in Ubercart settings indeed you have lightbox2 but it works for catalog only).

Comment: Anyway this is documentation: http://api.ubercart.org/api/function/uc_store_uc_image_widget/2/references?sort=desc&order=Name